# Cashback mechanism in Laravel site

Tags: laravel, affiliate, walmart-api

I want to make a cashback site for **Walmart** with Laravel but I have no idea how to track user's transaction.

I read that these are the steps basically:

- Attach extra parameters with all deeplinked URLs for dynamic user ID, click ID, coupon ID, merchant ID & network ID. Max 5 extra parameters are allowed by affiliate networks
- All links are usually routed through affiliate networks who capture sale happened via your website along with those passed on extra parameters. These sales are imported in your cashback website via affiliate network API
- Based on extra parameters, it’s allotted to the users in my site

The problem is that I can't find such API.

*Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that Walmart would willingly provide you with transaction data like this.

Comment: Ok, but how do websites like [Mr. Rebates](https://www.mrrebates.com/merchant.asp?id=592) and [Ebates](https://www.ebates.com/walmart.com?query=wa&position=1&type=suggest&store=2946) work?

Comment: @ceejayoz do you know how websites like [Mr. Rebates](https://www.mrrebates.com/merchant.asp?id=592) and [Ebates](https://www.ebates.com/walmart.com?query=wa&position=1&type=suggest&store=2946) work?

Comment: Probably via direct, contractual deals with the big vendors. Most of them started off as coupon code sites and got big enough to get deals.